# SQL - Inserting data based on multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I'm trying to insert a number of rows with different data based on the data in another table.

Scenario:

I have columns `tbl1_action` and `tbl1_actiondate`. 
I want to search in `tbl2` for a data in `tbl2_reviewdate` and `tbl2_destroydate`. If there is data in `tbl2_reviewdate` then I need `tbl1_action = 'review'` and `tbl1_actiondate = tbl2_reviewdate`. If there is data in `tbl2_destroydate` I need **another** row `tbl1_action = 'destroy'` and `tbl1_actiondate = tbl2_destroydate.`

So to summarise all possible scenarios:

```
If tbl2_ReviewDate IS NULL AND
   tbl2_DestroyDate IS NULL
```

Insert one record into tbl1 with action and actiondate = NULL

```
   tbl2_ReviewDate IS NOT NULL AND
   tbl2_DestroyDate IS NULL
Insert one row with tbl1_action = 'Review' and tbl1_actiondate = tbl2_reviewdate

   tbl2_ IS NULL AND
   tbl2_DestroyDate IS NOT NULL
Insert one row with tbl1_action = 'Destroy' and tbl1_actiondate = tbl2_destroydate

   tbl2_ReviewDate IS NOT NULL AND
   tbl2_DestroyDate IS NOT NULL
Insert two rows; One with tbl1_action = 'Destroy' and tbl1_actiondate = tbl2_destroydate and one with tbl1_action = 'Review' and tbl1_actiondate = tbl2_reviewdate.
```

Is it possible  to do this all in one script? What's the best way to do it?

Thanks your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
insert into table1(action, date)
    select 'Review', ActionDate
    from tbl2
    where tbl2.ReviewDate IS NOT NULL
    union all
    select 'Destroy', DestroyDate
    from tbl2
    where tbl2.DestroyDate IS NOT NULL;
```

You could also do this as two separate `insert` statements.